# Passing variables to main function in another JAVA class

Tags: java, variables, program-entry-point, args

In my main function of Helloworld.java class, I created a string or an object. Then, I created another class HelloAnotherClass.java. I want to pass my variable from Helloworld main() to main function of HelloAnotherClass.java.

```
package helloworld;
        public class HelloAnotherClass {
           public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        //... for example print passed variables
        }
```

How can I send the variables from HelloWorld main() to HelloAnotherClass main() using arguments or another structure of data and then return it againt to HelloWorld.java? Briefly, I vant to use main() function of another java class as a function in HelloWorld class.

that is the code sample I wrote

```
    HelloWorld { 
    /** * @param args the command line arguments */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    HelloAnotherClass.main("example"); 
    } 

public class HelloAnotherClass { 
    public static void main(String coming) throws IOException, ParseException { 
System.out.println(coming); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on *how* you want to run the other class.

If you want to run it in the current JVM, then you do it in the obvious way:

- Create an array of strings, containing the arguments.
- Call the `main` method with the array as a parameter.

If you want to run it in a new JVM, then you use System.exec(...) (or equivalent) with a command string that looks like it would if you were running `java` from the command line yourself.  (If the argument strings contain spaces, you want to use a specific Java installation, you want to use the same JVM options, etcetera ... it will be more complicated.)

The two approaches have advantages and disadvantages:

- Calling another classes `main` gives you fast "launch" times, but:

  1. the other class won't have an independent set of `System.in/out/err` streams because it shared statics with the original `main` class,
  2. if it calls `System.exit()` the entire JVM will exit,
  3. if it misbehaves, the original `main` class probably won't be able to get rid of it, and so on.
- Launching a separate JVM will result in significantly slower launch times, but the child JVM won't be able to interfere with the parent JVM.

---

Incidentally, the reason the your initial attempt failed is that you are passing a String rather than an array of Strings.  The compiler won't let you do that ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are running two independent programs and you want them to exchange data, then read about [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Answer (score 0):

The default `main` takes argument as `String[]`. Update `HelloAnotherClass` as below:

```
public class HelloWorld { 

   /** * @param args the command line arguments */ 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
        HelloAnotherClass.main(new String[]{"example"}); 
   }
}
```

If you try to print the args in `HelloAnotherClass` class, it would be as below:

```
public class HelloAnotherClass { 

  public static void main(String[] coming) throws IOException, ParseException {  
    System.out.println(coming[0]); 
  }
}
```

If you want to have another main method with `String` as parameter, that also can be done:

```
public class HelloWorld { 

    /** * @param args the command line arguments */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
       HelloAnotherClass.main("example"); 
    }
 }

 public class HelloAnotherClass { 

    public static void main(String coming) throws IOException, ParseException {  
       System.out.println(coming); 
    }
 }
```

Please let me know, if you are looking for some other/additional details.

Answer (score 0):

This is HelloWorld, with some arguments, ( I passed "Hello Crazy World")

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    //call static main method of Main2 class
    HelloAnotherWorld.main(args);
      //Modifcation made on Main2 is reflected
    System.out.println(args[1].toString());
}

}
```

This is HelloAnotherWorld

```
public static void main(String args[]) {        
    args[1]="foobar";
}
```

Since main is static in HelloAnotherWorld, you can call the main method as HelloAnotherWorld.main("array goes here");
Also note that , main returns void, so any attempt to pass primitives and return it would be unsuccessfull, unless you have overloaded main method.